# long run error after calling the javascript method from the action script

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am trying to call a method of a javascript from the actionscript using the ExternalInterface.
Here is the code in action script

```
private function onKickEvent(e:LogoutEvent):void{
                ExternalInterface.call("LoginFound","message");
                return;
        }
```

And this is my javascript mwthod

```
function LoginFound(message){
        alert(message);
    anotherInstanceExists=true;

}
```

Everything is working fine, but the only thing is when act on the alert box which is shown in the javascript after some 20 secs, the exception is thrown from the flash player that a script has been running longer than expected time 15 sec.

How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `js` function from the `actionscript`, that function *have to work and return value* not longer than in `15 sec`. `Javascript` works in *single thread*,and when you call `LoginFound` function, `alert` stops farther executions on the thread.

```
function LoginFound(message){
    alert('something');
    //Nothing will be executed unless `alert` window will be closed        
}
```

However you can handle such situation (the execution,which is longer than 15 sec) in `Actionsript` by using `try/catch`:

```
private function onKickEvent(e:LogoutEvent):void{
    try{
        ExternalInterface.call("LoginFound","message");
    }catch(e:Error){
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats really useful, but i have one more question, if i remove the flash object before the showing the alert box still am getting this error. why?

Comment: @VeeruAS What do you mean, by `'remove the flash object'`? removing `swf` ?

Comment: Yes removing the swf as $("#objectId").remove()

Comment: @VeeruAS Browser holds a reference to `swf` object,because `ExternalInterface.call("LoginFound","message")` execution is not finished yet and `swf` object waits for `LoginFound` function's return value,that is why you get an `exception`.

Comment: One more thing, is there any way where i can specify that dont wait for the javascipt method to return while calling the ExternalInterface.call()

Comment: then how can i unload the swf by calling the javascript function from the swf itself?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13998/discussion-between-engineer-and-veeru-a-s)

Answer (score 3):

Best way to fix this issue is to add setTimeout inside your javascript on the alert line.
It should look like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert(message) }, 1);
```

By doing it this way execution won't stop because of the alert.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `onKickEvent` is called frequently

so that the javascript is called regularly. finally the browser timeout event

occurs. It always happen in recursive function.

Comment: But am sure that the method is being called only once.